# VBA Code for name of previous month

Tags: vba, date, monthcalendar

I have added text in to my email that goes like:

"please provide numbers for MMMM month end" - where MMMM is the name of the previous month.

So it it's April today, MMMM will show March.

I have the following code:

```
Dim newDate: newDate = DateAdd("M", -1, Now)
```

But the result comes out to be 27/03/2017 16:37:58

I want it to show March.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Format the return as `"MMMM"`:

```
Dim newDate: newDate = Format(DateAdd("M", -1, Now), "MMMM")
```

Answer (score 2):

If set to True, the month name is abbreviated e.g. Apr

```
newDate = MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -1, Date)), False)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will ensure the month is in `English` irrespective of the regional settings on the computer. This will be helpful for those who are releasing an Excel VBA tool worldwide.

```
previousmonth = WorksheetFunction.Text(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "[$-409]mmmm")
```

For abbreviated months `eg: Apr` use

```
previousmonth = WorksheetFunction.Text(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "[$-409]mmm")
```